# Can I make this PDO shorter

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am creating a place where people can reserve tables. 
This is a project for school.

But the point is that I want to check in my database if the table is already reserved for the chosen date & time and if true, add a class to it so it becomes red, or something like that.

I have this code now but i don't want to do the same thing for table 2 - 18 because of the gigantic code I'll get. There must be an easier way. 
Anybody any ideas?

```
<?
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $time = $_GET['time'];
    ?>
    <button class="table 
    <?
    $table1 = $con->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `table` = 1 AND `date` = ? AND `time` = ?" );
    $table1->bindValue( 1, $date );
    $table1->bindValue( 2, $time );
    $table1->execute();
    if( $tafel1->rowCount() > 0 ) { echo "active";}
    ?>"></button>
```

Comment: Just parameterize your `table = ?` column as well. You can shorten the code it further with `->execute([$table, $date, $time])` instead of `->bindValue` calls.

Comment: Also you can select all `table` fields for a certain date and time. If table no exists in this selection - then it's active, else - not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work beautifully, taking full advantage of prepared statements:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
$query = $con->prepare("
    SELECT `id` -- if you don't have an ID column, replace with any column really
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `table` = ?
      AND `date` = ?
      AND `time` = ?
    LIMIT 1 -- you're only interested in existence, so limit 1 is more efficient
");
foreach(range(1,18) as $table) {
    $query->execute(array($table, $date, $time));
    if( $query->rowCount() > 0) $class = "table active";
    else $class = "table";

    echo '<button class="'.$class.'"></button>';
}
```